# What maximum size of animated GIF file can I attach to my StackExchange profile?

Tags: support, edits, profile-page

I tried to attach an animated GIF file to my StackExchange profile and I got the **Oops!** Message with the text below. It says it is the problem of the site, not mine. However my feeling is the issue could be related to the file size, because my file is about 6 Mbytes. Usually sites easily check the files size and the big files don't lead to the unpredictable behaviour or such an error page.

That's why I am asking about maximum allowed file size.

> We apologize for any inconvenience, but an unexpected error occurred
>   while you were browsing our site.
>
> It’s not you, it’s us. This is our fault.
>
> Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded
>   and we have been notified.
>
> Yes, we do look at every error. We even try to fix some of them.
>
> It’s not strictly necessary, but if you’d like to give us additional
>   information about this error, do so at our feedback site,
>   http://meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164023/animated-gif-profile-pic-on-stackoverflow-doesnt-animate

Comment: I don't see any explanation for unhandled errors there? If animated gifs aren't allowed surely a message explaining that would be preferable to the generic "our fault" error page.

Comment: @MartinSmith I agree with your comment.

Comment: The error message for trying to post an animated GIF should have an animated GIF. Like maybe [this one](http://thoughtcatalog.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/3.gif). That should send the appropriate message.

Comment: @CodyGray I'd opt for [this one](http://reactiongifs.me/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/no-hell-no.gif)

Comment: The issue is one of size - 6MB is too large for imgur to handle - the error is not more descriptive because the error returned by them for this isn't indicative of the issue, it is just a generic error message.

Answer (score 1):

There is a size limit to the Stack Exchange imgur - 6mb is over this limit.

When we try to upload a file of this size to imgur, they report an error. However, the error would be the same error as one given for any other issue with uploading an image. It is rather generic and doesn't have any details as to what the issue was.

So, we report that an error occurred.

Comment: Not that it is really worth fixing, but you *could* show an error message that indicated there was a problem with the *image*, rather than the generic "internal error" message. You wouldn't know exactly what the problem was with the image, but at least that would help narrow it down and suggest an actionable response to the user.

Comment: @CodyGray - thing is, we don't always know. It could be a network issue, it could be an issue with the image, it could be an internal error at imgur. We just don't know and the error given doesn't indicate the issue at all.